# Why when I use custom Material 3 ThemeData for my widget like ElevatedButton, it displays font family Roboto-regular weight 500 instead Roboto?

Tags: flutter, material-design, google-fonts, roboto

Why when I use custom Material 3 ThemeData - main color is green- for my widget like ElevatedButton, it displays font family Roboto-regular weight 500 instead Roboto as default-Material 3 in system - main color is purple. I have two question?

1. Why Roboto-regular has weight 500, whether it is the bug of Flutter? According to Google Fonts, Roboto-regular has weight 400.
   The images for my custom theme:
   [image: my custom material 3 theme]
   [image]
   [image: Roboto-regular weight 500]
2. I use my custom Material 3 but not similar to the Material 3 default system, because the text in Elevated Button is thinner than their (because of font family Roboto-regular)?
   The images for default:[image]
3. // Why the style doesn't affect to the text?

ElevatedButton(
child: Text('Roboto', style: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme().headlineLarge),
onPressed: () {}
)

The code for my implemention for my custome theme:[image]

I will zoom out the difference:[image]
[image]